# !function($) means what?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have some questions about jquery plugin - bootstrap-popover.js.

1. !function ($){ // meaning?
2. some lines have no semicolon and comma, why?
3. }(window.jQuery); // meaning?

---

```
!function ($) { //<--- 1. what does this line mean?

      "use strict"; // jshint ;_;

      var Popover = function (element, options) {

        this.init('popover', element, options) //<-- 2. this line has no semicolon, why...?

      }

      Popover.prototype = $.extend({}, $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.prototype, {
        ..................................
      })


      var old = $.fn.popover

      $.fn.popover = function (option) {
        return this.each(function () {

          var $this = $(this)
            , data = $this.data('popover')
            , options = typeof option == 'object' && option

          if (!data) $this.data('popover', (data = new Popover(this, options)))

          if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]() // <-- 3. this line has no semicolon no comma, why...?

        })

      }
    .......................................

    }(window.jQuery); // <-- 4. what does this line mean?
```

Comment: "2. some lines have no semicolon and comma, why?" – as default javascript adds semicolon to each new row ending. For more information: http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript / EMCA script, functions are values that can be passed around, called anonymously, or just plain used.

So, for example, the following is perfectly fine.

```
var square_something = function(x) { return x * x; };
alert(square_something(5));
```

Taking this concept a step further, we can do things like

```
alert(function(x) { return x * x; }(5));
```

That is to say, invoke (or call) the (anonymous) function with the value 5

Another wonderful feature of Javascript / ECMA script is that the character "$" is a perfectly valid variable name. So I can do

```
var $ = 5;
alert ($);
```

And I will see the value 5 perfectly fine. The jQuery library makes extensive use of this, as do other Javascript libraries. Or...

```
var myFunc = function($) { alert($ + 10); }
myFunc(32); // should alert the number 42
```

In jQuery extensions, you will often see this pattern...

```
function($) {
  // all the extension code...
}(window.jQuery);
```

Which is to say, invoke the anonymous function with the value window.jQuery. They do this because other Javascript libraries use the variable `$` but not the variable window.jQuery. This is a very subtle way to use the very short and convienent `$` instead of window.jQuery everywhere, only within the scope of the defined function.

To answer your "no semi-colon question"... There is no semi-colon on the line you mention because it is not required there. It would, however, be required if you had another line :)

Answer (score 3):

`!function ($) {...}(window.jQuery);` is equivalent to 
`(function ($) {...})(window.jQuery);` or 
`(function ($) {...})(window.jQuery);` which has the same behaviour.

It is a IIFE, self invoked function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

`(window.jQuery)` is the param passed to the anonymous function, this is to put `$` inside function refers to jQuery version passed as parameter.

Forget to tell about semi-colon. Following ECMAScript, semi-colons are optionnal, javascript engine are enough clever to find when add them when missing. But, as a side note, there is a particular behaviour:

Following code will always return 'undefined':

```
return
        1;
```

In this case, as a new line is detected and engine doesn't know what to return, a semi-colon will be added between return statement and value, giving:

```
return ;1;
```

So use: `return 1;` without new line between it. `return 1` will works too, of course.